# Google Awareness Location Fence is not working

Tags: google-awareness

I tried using Google Awareness API for Location Fence:
https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-google-awareness-api-bf45f8060bba

But it's not working all times, is there any special trick?

Answer (score 0):

please refer this blog.
its working fine.
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/google-awareness-api-in-action/en